# Question about the quotient ring $k[x]/(f(x))$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and $k$ its fraction field. Let $f(x), g(x)$ be two irreducible polynomials in $k[x]$ and suppose that $\varphi:k[x]/(f(x))\cong k[x]/(g(x))$. Is it true that $k[x]/(f(x)^n)\cong k[x]/(g(x)^n)$ for all positive integers $n$? Assume further that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in $R[x]$, is it true that $\varphi(x+(f(x)))=t(x)+(g(x))$ for some $t(x)\in R[x]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the first question, if $\varphi$ is $k$-linear and $f$ is separable yes. By Hensel lemma $f$ has a root $a$ in $k[x]/(g(x)^n)$,

$K=k[a]$ is a field and $k[x]/(g(x)^n)$ is a $K$-algebra.

The $K$-minimal polynomial of $g(x)+(g(x)^n)$ is $T^n$ and $k[x]/(g(x)^n)$ contains $K[g(x)+(g(x)^n)]\cong K[T]/(T^n)$, comparing the $k$-vector space dimensions (as $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$) we have $k[x]/(g(x)^n)\cong K[T]/(T^n)$.

The same argument gives that $k[y]/(f(y)^n)\cong K[T]/(T^n)$.

- For the second question no, try with $R=\Bbb{Z},f=2x-1,g=x$.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer!